# Getting Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" error and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs

So what I am trying to do, and have been doing without problems, is pass a function to a child component, and that child component returns a value and finally, that returned value is set inside the parent's state in the parent component. It looks like this:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {active: false, currId: ""};
  };

  setStateFromChild(val, id){
    this.setState({active: val, currId: id});
  }

  renderChildren() {
    return this.props.data.map( (item) => 
        <ChildComponent returnState={this.setStateFromChild.bind(this)} active={this.state.currId === item.id ? true : false} id={item.id}/>
      )
  }

  render(){
    return(<div>{this.renderChildren()}</div>)
  }

}
```

Then Child component...

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {active: props.active}
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.active !== this.state.active){
      this.setState({active: nextProps.active});
    }
  }

  handleChange(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.returnState(!this.state.active, this.props.id);
  }

  render(){
    return(<button className={this.state.active ? "green button" : "grey button"} onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>Select Option</button>)
  }
}
```

Then I get the following error:

> "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {key, val}). If you meant to render a collection of
>   children, use an array instead or wrap the object using
>   createFragment(object) from the React add-ons."

I don't see where the object is a rendered React child anywhere. The only object I have is the state change itself in the parent component. I did this multiple times and never had a problem until this one specific component. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I also have to add that that setting the state works, but this error keeps printing in the console and slows down my app. I don't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: Not sure. However, `renderChildren` doesn't return anything.

Comment: This works https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/64979/